# Record live audio aka Stereo Mix in WIndows 10 or 11 with ffmpeg - Windows WASAPI

Tags: audacity, windows, ffmpeg, signal-routing

Long story short it seems that StereoMix heavily used in past was a feature of the sound card and sound drivers, so... it's not possible to use it if it isn't present on the machine.

`C:\Users\user\Desktop> ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`

```
ffmpeg version N-94077-g01d8c72b95 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 29.100 / 56. 29.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.100 / 58. 53.100
  libavformat    58. 28.100 / 58. 28.100
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
[dshow @ 0000020a1ff08b00] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 0000020a1ff08b00]  "HP Truevision HD"
[dshow @ 0000020a1ff08b00]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_064e&pid_9301&mi_00#6&a1a3a63&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 0000020a1ff08b00] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 0000020a1ff08b00]  "Microphone (High Definition Audio Device)"
[dshow @ 0000020a1ff08b00]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{412CABE0-42CF-45FB-96DF-D9A61252AADE}"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

Recently I updated my os from win7 to win10 and the StereoMix feature disappeared.

It turned out that windows has a new api called WASAPI and it works by allowing you to record the live audio from the computer by re-reouting the stereo output into the input. Audacity seems to be able to do it.

[image: Audacity WASAPI setting]

Can ffmpeg access WASAPI devices and allow them to be used for recording? So that I can bypass the problem using WASAPI like Audacity does.